# Latex Table (Graphix) Help! Is it possible to draw?

Tags: tables, graphics, diagrams

I would like to draw these following diagram (table or graphix) in latex (i attached them), is it possible?[image: []

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and _always_ possible. Have a look at Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried so far?

Comment: For the second image, you might be interested in using a `tikz matrix`.